# Why can't I create an offset path for my PSD Images on Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, path

I'm currently in the process of ***making stickers*** for my ETSY Shop. I have made all my sheets in Photoshop and decided to transfer one file into Illustrator.

As I was trying to make a cut line for my machine I realized I wasn't seeing any of the **points** (I don't know what they're called) whenever I hovered over my image. The only thing it would show me was the box surrounding it. I have also noticed that it won't even let me use the "offset path" option and image tracing doesn't do much either because I still cannot create an outline.

Do I need to restart all these sheets completely on illustrator? Any advice would be so helpful.

(i've also tried saving my file as PNG, TIFF, when I was image tracing I made sure it wasn't using the white space, but **nothing is working**.)

Answer (score 2):

Photoshop files are only accessible as placed/embedded raster images within Illustrator. Illustrator's Offset feature only works on vector path data, not placed/embedded raster images.

You see an box with an X in it to indicate the object is a *raster* image, not vector content.

If you have vector paths in Photoshop, you can choose the Photoshop menu - `File > Export > Paths to Illustrator`. That will create an Illustrator document containing all the *paths*. But they will be unfilled, un stroked paths. So you'll need to switch to outline mode in Illustrator (`View > Outline`) to select them, then reapply any fills or strokes.

While the two applications do share *some* common ground, files between them are not immediately the same. The core code to build art is drastically different in many instance.